# detecting a property of an item before placing it in array

Tags: c#, arrays, object, boolean, conditional-statements

I am attempting to add a card into a hand from a deck (cardArray) and not allow duplicates. in the SuperCard class I made a property of bool called inPlay. when the Program.cs starts, theres a "shuffle" method that sets all cards inPlay bool to false. I'm trying to figure out how to keep from drawing the same card, and i was attempting if/else if but that isnt working. when I leave off the else if, it runs into an "no instance of object" exception. here's the code as is. any help would be amazing. Thanks!

```
public SuperCard[] GetCards(int number)
{ 
    SuperCard[] hand = new SuperCard[number];
    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)
    {
        int x = myRandom.Next(0, 51);
        if (cardArray[x].inPlay == false)
        {
            hand[i] = cardArray[myRandom.Next(0, 51)];
            cardArray[x].inPlay = true;
        }
        else if (cardArray[x].inPlay == true) 
        {
            hand[i] = cardArray[myRandom.Next(0, 51)];

        }
    }
    return hand;
}
```

Comment: When you draw a card just remove it from the deck.

Comment: @Muctadir I'm not entirely sure how to do that :\ also, would I have to recreate the deck each "round"?

Comment: Just remove the drawn element from the deck array. And to recreate deck instantiate a new deck.

Comment: Have a look at my answer's links ... one of them deals directly with shuffling a deck of cards ...

Comment: @Muctadir & Noctis: for the sake of this program, I am trying to keep it in arrays and not lists. I need better comprehension of arrays and their behaviors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this one

```
public SuperCard[] GetCards(int number)
{

    SuperCard[] hand = new SuperCard[number];
    int index;

    for (int i = 0; i < number; i++)  // 5 cards
    {
        index = myRandom.Next(0, 51);
        hand[i] = cardArray[index];
        while (hand[i].inplay == true)
        {  
            index = myRandom.Next(0, 51);
            hand[i] = cardArray[index];

        }
        hand[i].inplay = true;    
    }

    return hand;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem I think is you use `x` for checking `inPlay` property but use `myRandom.Next(0, 51)` again to draw the card in the first `if` statement.

In the `else if` statement, I guess you try to draw another card, which is not checked `inPlay` property.

The solution is creating a new method which finds the new card having `inPlay == false`. In that method, you should loop until get that card or out of card in your deck.

Answer (score 0):

**First**, I've change your code to this:

```
public SuperCard[] GetCards(int cards_to_get)
{ 
    SuperCard[] hand = new SuperCard[cards_to_get];
    for (int i = 0; i < cards_to_get; i++)
    {
        int x = myRandom.Next(0, 51);

        if (cardArray[x].inPlay)
            hand[i] = cardArray[myRandom.Next(0, 51)];  
        else {
            hand[i] = cardArray[myRandom.Next(0, 51)];
            cardArray[x].inPlay = true;
        }
    }
    return hand;
}
```

**Second**, how where and when do you initialize the cardArray ?

**Third**, as the comment suggests, you can just have a List of cards, shuffle the list, and take the `first cards_to_get` using the `ListName.Take(cards_to_get)` for example .

You can have a look for shuffling [here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/shuffle), [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/553112/How-I-Use-Csharp-to-Shuffle-a-Sequentially-Ordered), or just search SO for shuffling a list.

**Edit:**
Ok ... here's what you do ... you get a random card in here: `int x = myRandom.Next(0, 51);`

Then you say , if it's not in play **(should be added)** let's add it... only ... you add a random card:

```
 hand[i] = cardArray[myRandom.Next(0, 51)];
        cardArray[x].inPlay = true;
```

You should have added the `cardArray[x]` . Thish should solve your problem.

Another issue, is in the next bit, where you say:  **Else, add a new random card**

```
else if (cardArray[x].inPlay == true) 
{
        hand[i] = cardArray[myRandom.Next(0, 51)];
}
```

But here you'll add a new random card, without checking if it's in play or not.

:)

Comment: I intialize cardArray in the CardSet constructor (Where this GetCards method is in). looks like this: 

`public CardSet() 
        {
            cardArray = new SuperCard[52];
            for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++)
            {
                cardArray[i] = new CardClubs((Rank)i + 1);
                cardArray[i + 13] = new CardDiamond((Rank)i+1);
                cardArray[i + 26] = new CardHeart((Rank)i + 1); ;
                cardArray[i + 39] = new CardSpades((Rank)i + 1); ;
            }
        }`

also your edited code still came up with duplicate cards. :\

Comment: My edited code was about your style, not about correctness. For that you had the **Third** one ... I'll give this new code a look in a couple of min

Answer (score 0):

The simplest would be to just remove the card from the deck. After all that's what happens in the world you are modelling. And when modelling the real world closely these kinds of issues tend to go away. However you can make a simple fix to the code and it would then work

```
public SuperCard[] GetCards(int number)
{ 
    SuperCard[] hand = new SuperCard[number];
    while(number>0)
    {
        int x = myRandom.Next(0, 51);
        if (cardArray[x].inPlay == false)
        {
            hand[hand.Length - number] = cardArray[myRandom.Next(0, 51)];
            cardArray[x].inPlay = true;
            number--;
        }
    }
    return hand;
}
```

Comment: if we are taking out the for loop, what would we change the i in hand[i] to? hand[number]?